# Voltage jump in time series data acquisition

Tags: power-supply, communication, strain-gage

This might be a basic question, but I am a Mechanical Engineer and hence stumped. I am acquiring (output) time series data from Strain gauge (excited by amplifiers). Attached plot is the output (ADC voltage time series) recorded by my data acquisition hardware/software (X-time, Y-voltage). I don't understand the source of these jumps. I installed an APC to eliminate the irregular power supply, but it did not help.[image]
I can provide more details about the setup if required.

Comment: I would say this is from RFI, information of your entire setup will be necessary, including the cabling (shielding) and amplifiers you may be using. EMI problems are system problems and usually related to the entire system.

Comment: The horizontal scale is in seconds (i.e. 0 to 400,000 s)?

Comment: If so, the period looks very roughly around to 1 day (86,000 s). Look for things like AC cycling on and off, room lights on and off, other big electrical loads in the building that cycle daily. For strain guages the interference could conceivably be acoustic rather than electrical.

Comment: I agree with @The Photon,  also look at any electrical interference.  Heat pump or fluorescent light switching.  Might even be power supply related, input voltage changes caused by hot water heater.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. However weird it might sound, these jumps were caused by the computer while recording the data. After connecting a ground wire from the strain guage to the computer, we were able to eliminate these jumps.